# my input return me undefined even though the data is catch. using CRUD js

Tags: javascript, crud

```
<body>

    <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="app.Add()"> 
        <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="New country ">
        <input type="number" id="add-popu" placeholder="New population">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

    <div id="spoiler" role="aria-hidden">
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
            <input type="text" id="edit-name">
            <input type="text" id="edit-popu">
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <p id="counter"></p>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody id="countries"></tbody>
        <tbody id="popultns"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    <script>
    var app = new function() 
    {   this.el = document.getElementById('countries');
        this.el = document.getElementById('popultns');
        let loadTableData = data2;
        this.Count = function(data) 
        {   var el   = document.getElementById('counter');
            var name = 'country2';
            var pop = 'popu2'
            if (data) 
            {   if (data > 1) 
                {   name = 'countries' ;
                    pop = "popultns" ;
                }

                el.innerHTML = data + ' ' + name + ' ' + pop ;
            } 
            else 
                {   el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name + ' ' + pop  ;  }
        };

        this.FetchAll = function() 
        {   var data = '';
            if (loadTableData.length > 0) 
            {   for (i = 0; i < loadTableData.length; i++) 
                {   data += '<tr>';
                    data += '<td>' + loadTableData[i].country + '</td>';
                    data += '<td>' + loadTableData[i].population + '</td>';
                    data += '<td><button onclick="app.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
                    data += '<td><button onclick="app.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
                    data += '</tr>';
                }
            }

            this.Count(loadTableData.length);
            return this.el.innerHTML = data;
        };

        this.Add = function () 
        {   el = document.getElementById('add-name');
            el2 = document.getElementById('add-popu');
            // Get the value
            var country2 = el.value;
            var pop = el2.value;

            if (country2) 
            {   // Add the new value
                loadTableData.push(country2.trim() );

                // Reset input value
                el.value = '';
                //el2.value = '';
                // Dislay the new list
                this.FetchAll();
            }
        };
```

[the image is the ui tht im working for the  function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wxGb.png) 
I'm supposed to auto-generate the table based on the data available from my main.js script which is in JSon format. There is no problem with the data loading since the data can be display in my html file. However, the problem comes whn my data is returned undefined on my auto generated table whn i click the 'add' button to update the data in the table. Whn i click in the edit button, the data is get correctly. only whn the display, it returns me undefined.

Comment: where define data2 .It may cause error .You may provide globaly      let loadTableData = [];

Comment: i did define it tho in the function 

let loadTableData = data2;

anyway, i got tht one alrdy. however whn i make a change with it, it makes either my data display as undefined whn i click on the edit button or, i can let my edit function works but the data would display undefined

Comment: dis is the latest code (the one tht i can display correctly w/o undefined)

this.Add = function () 
   { el = document.getElementById('add-name');
    el2 = document.getElementById('add-popu');
    // Get the value
    var country2 = el.value;
    var popltn = el2.value;
 
    if (country2 && popltn ) 
    { // Add the new value
     //loadTableData.push(country2.trim() );
     loadTableData.push({country: country2, population:popltn});
     // Reset input value
     el.value = '';
     el2.value = '';
     // Dislay the new list
     this.FetchAll();
    }
   };

Comment: however, it disrupts my edit function (in which it cant edit n display anymore). so it either way,  only 1 function i can do, if i recode the undefined display, the edit button disrupts.  and if i let the undefined remained, my edit function works

Comment: Hi can display api.edit function

Comment: can display, but whn u click function it cant

Comment: '<td><button onclick="app.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>'; here you place double quated aftyer ) BRACKET which is not started.Insted of that use single quated '

Comment: its ok, i knw wht is wrong alry. tq for ur help ^^

Answer (score 0):

i know how alrdy. 
here i attach the code & sample of the data i hv done.
hopefully this would help fresh grad like me who hv trouble in undrsntdng CRUD

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Countries CRUD</title>
   <style>
  input[type='submit'], button, [aria-label]{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #spoiler{
    display: none;
  }
   </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="app.Add()"> 
   <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="New country ">
   <input type="number" id="add-popu" placeholder="New population">
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>

  <div id="spoiler" role="aria-hidden">
   <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
    <input type="text" id="edit-name">
    <input type="text" id="edit-popu">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
   </form>
  </div>

  <p id="counter"></p>

  <table>
    <tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
   <tbody id="countries"></tbody>
   <tbody id="popultns"></tbody>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  var app = new function() 
  { this.el = document.getElementById('countries' && 'popultns');
   //this.el = document.getElementById('popultns');
   let loadTableData = data2;
   this.Count = function(data) 
   { var el   = document.getElementById('counter');
    var name = 'country2';
    var pop = 'popu2'
    if (data) 
    { if (data > 1) 
     { name = 'countries' ;
      pop = "populations" ;
     }
     
     el.innerHTML = data + ' ' + name + ' ' + pop ;
    } 
    else 
     { el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name + ' ' + pop  ; }
   };
    
   this.FetchAll = function() 
   { var data = '';
    
    if (loadTableData.length > 0) 
    { for (i = 0; i < loadTableData.length; i++) 
     { data += '<tr>';
      data += '<td>' + loadTableData[i].country + '</td>';
      data += '<td>' + loadTableData[i].population + '</td>';
      data += '<td><button onclick="app.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
      data += '<td><button onclick="app.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
      data += '</tr>';
     }
    }
   
    this.Count(loadTableData.length);
    return this.el.innerHTML = data;
   };
   
   this.Add = function () 
   { el = document.getElementById('add-name');
    el2 = document.getElementById('add-popu');
    
    
    // Get the value
    var country2 = el.value;
    var popltn = el2.value;
 
    if (country2 && popltn ) 
    { // Add the new value
     //loadTableData.push(country2.trim() );
     loadTableData.push({country: country2, population:popltn});
     // Reset input value
     el.value = '';
     el2.value = '';
     // Dislay the new list
     this.FetchAll();
    }
   };
   
   this.Edit = function (item) 
   { var el3 = document.getElementById('edit-name');
    var el4 = document.getElementById('edit-popu');
    // Display value in the field
    let index = item;
    el3.value = loadTableData[index].country;
    el4.value = loadTableData[index].population;

    // Display fields
    document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = 'block';
    self = this;
    document.getElementById('saveEdit').onsubmit = function() 
    {
     // Get value
     var country2 = el3.value;
     var popltn = el4.value;
     
     //console.log({country2, pop});
     
     if (country2 || pop) 
     //console.log(country2);
     { // Edit value (strt,del,replace)
      console.log(country2,popltn);
      console.log(index, 1,({country2,popltn}));
      //update array
      loadTableData[index].country = el3.value;
      loadTableData[index].population = el4.value;
      //self.loadTableData.splice(index, 1,({country2,popltn}));
      //console.log(index, 1, pop.trim());
      //self.loadTableData.splice(index, 1, pop.trim());
      // Display the new list
      self.FetchAll();
      // Hide fields
      CloseInput();
     }
    }
   };
   
   this.Delete = function (item) 
   {
   // Delete the current row
   loadTableData.splice(item, 1);
   // Display the new list
   this.FetchAll();
   };
    
  }
  
  app.FetchAll();
  function CloseInput() 
  { document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = 'none';}
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```